# VS IDE 2022 - Intellicode suggestions failed to start

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When I open a solution in VS 2022, I get the following error.

Task Failed - Activating language client IntelliCode suggestions: IntelliCode suggestions failed to start. The initialization error was logged and will be reported to the IntelliCode team.

Comment: For me this problem started after removing GitHub Copilot (which seems to require Intellicode). Other things broke as well (e.g. no more tooltips when you hover over a function name expecting to see its XML docs). Removing Intellicode entirely seems to have resolved some of the issues (but I still get high CPU usage when typing).

Answer (score 3):

I'll post the fix that worked for me.

Make sure VS IDE is closed. Open the Visual Studio Installer and repair the VS IDE where the Intellicode failed to start.

Restart PC after the repair has completed.

This is the only way I could get it to work again. Either that or a complete re-install. I've chosen to repair instead of a complete re-install.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> Please try:

> Go to Visual Studio Installer, click Modify, uncheck IntelliCode in Individual components, then click Modify button to save the change, wait for the installation to complete, and then reinstall IntelliCode.
> In Visual Studio, go to Tools->Options->IntelliCode to check if the setting is Default.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72025586/6723966